# My PC is very slow, opening explorer takes 5-10 min to load properly

Tags: windows-10, memory, performance

I have a laptop with the following specs: i5-6200U, 8GB LPDDR3L RAM, 240GB SATA SSD(Boot and C Drive without any partitions) + 1TB HDD.

My PC can't handle 3 programs at once right now. It always freezes the transfer if i do any for about 4-5 hrs or more, irrespective of the size or number of files transferred. I have scanned the PC with Windows Defender, but there isn't anything there. I've seen that page faults go high as the program gets freezed or taking a lot of time load.
And also the CPU temps at idle are always above 50C, mostly above 55C, at about 5-10% CPU usage.

What could be the reason for this behavior and what would be the solution for that?

---

Edit: I have uploaded SMART attributes of the Boot drive.

[image]

Comment: Try running some third-party Windows 10 PE based Live CD off USB (e.g. Hiren Boot DVD)  and re-check the performance. Try Clean Boot approach for a few days and re-check the performance.

Answer (score 0):

> I have scanned the PC with Windows Defender but there isn't anything
> there.

5- 10 minutes to load Explorer is vastly too slow.

Get the Manufacturer's Hardware Diagnostic App, scan for hardware issues including both drives.

Resolve any hardware issues.

Then back up and reinstall Windows. Make sure Windows, Windows System, Program Files, Basic User Folders, and anything Windows needs is on Drive C.

Look in the Properties of Documents to see how to relocate the folder.

Only keep Documents, Photos, Videos and similar non-Windows files on the HDD.

Comment: manufacturer's hardware diagnostic app, windows diagnostic tool, bios diagnose. I have them all but nothing comes out of it they say its all working fine. 

I have reinstalled the windows several times but nothing changes, for few days  it works fine then again same problem. 
All my windows and application files are in Drive C which is SSD, it has no partitions  whole 240gb for it, and hdd is for personal files.

Comment: There would seem to be a hardware error of some sort. 10 minutes to open Explorer would indicate that. One person here suggested more memory. You can try that, but I have worked with numerous 8 GB machines that performed very well.

Comment: its not always the case sometimes it opens instantly. So to elaborate, when I turn on my laptop and open Explorer it instantly opens sometimes, and when I open and close it for few times like 4-5 times then on the 6th time it takes 5-10 mins. And whenever I Plug my external HDD it always takes 5-10 min no matter how less I have opened it.

Comment: I will do some thinking, What you describe (10 minutes to open a file explorer) has not happened to me on any machine back to DOS 1.0 or on any customer machine in 2 decades.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer seems to have serious hardware problems.

You need more information to analyze the problem :

- Open the Event Viewer and look for useful error messages.
- Take a screenshot and add to your post of the SMART attributes of
  the disk. If you don't have a product for it, you could use
  [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy).
- Run [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) to test your memory
  and also the general functioning of the computer.

This information should better pinpoint the problem.

Comment: I tried memtest86 but it doesn't boot with the v5 or v10 whatever was that and yes I used UEFI boot for that, it just shows the screen where it checks the hardware info after checking the screen goes blank, I left it overnight to load but still blank screen so I tried v4 version with legacy boot this time it does the test but no error in that test.

Comment: You should run MemTest86 overnight. Your SMART data looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Page faults probably indicate low memory. Windows starts moving data from memory to the disk when it gets low, then a page fault happens when a program wants information that it expected in memory but it is no longer there. Windows must fetch it from the disk instead, which takes much longer. This slows everything down because your disk is busier than it should be AND the program you're trying to use has to wait for the information to load.

It is very easy to use up 8gb of memory in Windows 10 or 11, even just with things running in the background that you may not notice, like a virus scanner or chat application. I'd recommend upgrading to at least 16gb if possible.

I wouldn't worry about the CPU temperature unless it goes over 70C or so.

Comment: I understand that 8gb is kind of less for windows but still I dont think 8gb is less for just casual browsing and media even after Apps running in background unless they are like norton or heavy usage ones. But I dont have any apps running in background atleast what I saw in the hidden icons in taskbar and apps running in task manager.

Comment: 8GB is enough, you don't really need to upgrade and most important it's not the source of the problem described.